# Select rows where values for different columns are NOT a certain value in R

Tags: r

I have 6 different columns:
call_outcome_1 - call_outcome_6

Each one can be a value from 0-5 (0=caller reached, 2=left message, etc..)

I am trying to select rows where none of these 6 columns =0 (aka, the person was never reached)

However, some of these values are NA. For example,if the person was reached on the first call, then call_outcomes 2-6 will be NA.

I tried:

```
not_interviewed=data %>%
  filter(call_outcome_1 !=0 & call_outcome_2!=0 & call_outcome_2 !=0 & call_outcome_3 !=0 & call_outcome_4 !=0 & call_outcome_5 !=0 & call_outcome_6 !=0) %>%
  select(record_id)
not_interviewed
```

This gives me records where all 6 call attempts are filled out (no NAs) and none of them are 0. It excludes records where there are NA values for any of the outcomes. I have tried na.rm=FALSE and get an error. Any help would be appreciated, I am fairly new to R :)

Comment: Hard to help without example data, but how about `filter_at(your_df, vars(starts_with('call_outcome')), all_vars(. > 0 | is.na(.)))`

Answer (score 0):

You could check if its different from zero or it's NA with this code:

```
filter( (call_outcome_1 !=0 |is.na(call_outcome_1)==TRUE) & (call_outcome_2 !=0 |is.na(call_outcome_2)==TRUE) ...continue... & (call_outcome_6 !=0 |is.na(call_outcome_6)==TRUE))  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider this simple example :

```
data <- data.frame(a = 1:5, call_outcome_1 = c(0, NA, 1, 2, 0), 
                   call_outcome_2 = c(NA, 2, 1, 2, 3))
data
#  a call_outcome_1 call_outcome_2
#1 1              0             NA
#2 2             NA              2
#3 3              1              1
#4 4              2              2
#5 5              0              3
```

To select rows where none of the value is 0 you can use `rowSums`

```
cols <- grep('call_outcome', names(data))
data[rowSums(data[cols] == 0, na.rm = TRUE) == 0, ]

#  a call_outcome_1 call_outcome_2
#2 2             NA              2
#3 3              1              1
#4 4              2              2
```